# Stop Snappy module not found in eslint

Tags: ios, reactjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to launch my ionic app onto the app store using Appflow (Ionic, MERN stack) but when running build I get an error with Snappy saying `modules not found`

I am trying to ignore this from my files so I can deploy as I am unable to install them onto my MacOS

[image]

This is impacting my deployment as AppFlow is picking up the error and erroring out.

I've tried creating and adding to my .eslintignore:

```
node_modules/
app/node_modules/
client/dist/
```

But I still get error, the full build error is:

```
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.android-arm64.node' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.darwin-arm64.node' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.darwin-x64.node' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.freebsd-x64.node' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-arm-gnueabihf.node' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-arm64-gnu.node' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-arm64-musl.node' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-x64-gnu.node' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-x64-musl.node' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.win32-arm64-msvc.node' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.win32-ia32-msvc.node' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.win32-x64-msvc.node' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-android-arm64' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-darwin-arm64' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-freebsd-x64' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-linux-arm-gnueabihf' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-linux-arm64-gnu' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-linux-arm64-musl' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-linux-x64-gnu' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-linux-x64-musl' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-win32-arm64-msvc' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-win32-ia32-msvc' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-win32-x64-msvc' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/encrypter.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve 'mongodb-client-encryption' in '/Users/bradleykirkland/YRepo/KPA/node_modules/mongodb/lib'
[react-scripts] Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
[react-scripts] To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

I've checked and made sure I've added my ignore file to the root, if anyone has gone through this with trying to release an ionic react app please help